# PHP Remove everything before a character

Tags: php

So i have this in my test.txt file:

```
5436 : Ball Of Yarn
1849 : Blue Border Collie Headband
24063 : Blue Border Collie Hoodie
```

I'm trying to remove everything before the ":", this is my PHP code:

```
$str = file_get_contents("test.txt");
$string2 = substr($str, ($pos = strpos($str, ' : ')) !== false ? $pos + 1 : 0);
file_put_contents("test.txt", $string2);
```

Help me please

Comment: You need to do that *for each line*. It won't work on the whole file like that.

Comment: @JohnConde What can I do then?

Comment: Rethink using this format. @JohnConde is right.

Comment: @dwhite.me I have no idea

Comment: @user3334215: Try using this `$string2 = preg_replace('/^[^:]+:\s/m', '', $str);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
$arr = file("test.txt");
foreach ($arr as $line) {
   echo substr($line, ($pos = strpos($line, ' : ')) !== false ? $pos + 1 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid to use regex you can use this: (works if your characters before : are numbers only). If you need other chars let me know.

```
$str = file_get_contents("test.txt");
$string2 = preg_replace('/[0-9 ]+:/', "", $str);
file_put_contents("test.txt", $string2);
```

This does what you wanted exactly and keeps your structure; just second line is changed :)

See more about regex [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html) or in [this](http://www.icewarp.com/support/online_help/203030104.htm) basic tutorial which looks nice to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `fgetcsv`. Here is an example of use :

```
$ cat test.txt
5436 : Ball Of Yarn
1849 : Blue Border Collie Headband
24063 : Blue Border Collie Hoodie
$ cat test.php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    $in_file="test.txt";
    if (false !== ($handle = fopen($in_file, "r"))){
        while(false !== ($line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ":"))){
            if(isset($line[1]) && $line[1]){
                echo "LINE=" . trim($line[1]) . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
?>
$ ./test.php
LINE=Ball Of Yarn
LINE=Blue Border Collie Headband
LINE=Blue Border Collie Hoodie
```

Another solution using `preg_replace` :

```
$ cat test.php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    $in_file="test.txt";
    if (false !== ($handle = fopen($in_file, "r"))){
        while(false !== ($line = fgets($handle))){
            echo "LINE=" . trim(preg_replace("/^[^:]*:\ ?([^:]*)$/", "$1", $line)) . "\n";
        }
    }
?>
$ ./test.php
LINE=Ball Of Yarn
LINE=Blue Border Collie Headband
LINE=Blue Border Collie Hoodie
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using array_map to alter the contents of each line then write to the file, with perhaps a better way of stripping the line for you:

```
function editLine($line) {
    return strstr($line, ':') ?: $line;
}

$lines = file('test.txt');
$editedLines = array_map('editLine', $lines);
file_put_contents('test.txt', implode('', $editedLines));
```